# directive $watch does not get invoked on class change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, smartadmin

I have an angular app, using a left menu, with a show/hide menu bar, the action to show/hide on the left menu is a "data-action". I am using Smart Admin and the code is as below

```
<span class="minifyme" data-action="minifyMenu"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i> </span>
```

When the data-action is fired, the body section class is changed or gets appeded a new class.

My requirement is to do something on the change of the class. I have a directive on the body to $watch for class.

The directive code surely gets invoked on load of the page, but it does not when the class is changed, i.e. when the data-action is performed.

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("myApp");

var myDirective = [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            initialize();

            scope.$watch(function () {
             return element.attr('class');
        }, function (newValue) {
            if (element.hasClass('test')) {
                console.log('has class.');
            } else {
                console.log('classremoved.');
            }
        });

            function initialize() {

            };
        }
    };
}];

app.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

}());
```

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: can you post your full code to give  a detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in $apply() method as data-action is out of angular context.

Comment: call $apply in minifyMenu()

Comment: As I said it is part of the smart admin. and I do not have any more detail that the one I posted above, i am sorry.

Comment: Post your full HTML too.